# How to buy ether in Costa rica

Tags: blockchain, coinbase, cex-io

I am wanting to create a paper wallet in Costa Rica and buy ether with us checking account. Coinbase will not work in Costa Rica. Please tell me what you know will work. What exchanges will work and what else do I need to know. thank you Rain

Answer (score 1):

If there's no fiat to crypto exchange in Costa Rica, then you can probably use a service like [localbitcoins](https://localbitcoins.com/country/CR) to buy bitcoins from someone using cash and then exchange bitcoin to ether on a crypto exchange that doesn't require KYC to sign up, like [binance](https://www.binance.com/).

Comment: this answer is a guess. Probably!!!! Come on you guys. There has to he someone with a answer. Buying coins with cash ? We do have internet here. Why does coinbas not work with Costa Rica.??